# How do you create a computed column with a condition that also sums up multiple columns from several rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do you create a computed column with a condition that also sums up multiple columns from several rows.

Say I have the following DATA in a table:

[image]

I get that I can do:

```
 select distinct Funded_Amount + Direct_Amount as Fuel,
 from ....
```

in my selection list to get it to add up the Funded and Direct costs, but I need some way to do it for each row that has the same tractor and driver numbers and then consolidate the funded and direct rows into a sum called fuel. So that it goes from the table above... to something like the one below.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.
*Any data in these tables is not actual customer data due to privacy and is simply random data that I came up with as a placeholder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just use a group by to do this:

```
SELECT order, tractor, driver, sum(Funded_Amount + Direct_Amount) as fuel
FROM table
GROUP BY order, tractor, driver
```

Comment: When I use a 'group by' syntax... it then wants me to put every column that's specified in the select list into the group by. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: You either have to put each column in the group by, or tell it how you want to aggregate that column with an aggregate formula like `avg()`, or `max()` or the like.. There is no way around that.

Comment: Ok I got it to work, but I'm still getting some duplicates so let me see what it's doing and get back with you.

Comment: OK. Decide what you want to do with those duplicates, like which value is the one you want, then with that information you can craft SQL to make that value be the chosen one. Feel free to ask a new question for that specific problem.

Comment: I think this will work for what I need. Thank you so much for you help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
    select order, tractor,driver,sum(funded + direct) fuel
    group by order, tractor,driver

Answer (score 0):

WHy wouldn't a group by suffice?

```
 Select tractor, driver, 
   Sum(Funded_Amount + Direct_Amount) TotalFuel
 From table
 Group By tractor, driver
```